# Batch file / Powershell script to zip files in folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, zip

I have a lot of folders with files inside for example:

`Folder1` with sample content:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.xml
File4.jpg
.
.
.
```

Result after zip: `Folder1.zip`

`Folder2` with sample content:

```
File12.txt
File22.txt
File32.xml
File42.jpg
.
.
```

Result after zip: `Folder2.zip`

How to zip only all files (not entire folder) in every folder with result filename like "Foldername.zip". I found this code `for /d %%a in (*) do (ECHO zip -r -p "%%~na.zip" ".\%%a\*")` but it zips entire folders, not only files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following steps:

1. create empty zip file
2. copy this file to all folders in "working folder"
3. rename all zip files with folder name
4. add .txt, .jpg, .xml files to zip.

This is a working code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A:D /B') do (
xcopy /y "Path_to_empty_zip\Test.zip" ".\%%~na\"
rename "%%~na\Test.zip" "%%~na.zip"
)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A:D /B') do (  
cd "Path_to_working_folder\%%~na\"
zip -r "%%~na.zip" "*.txt"
zip -r "%%~na.zip" "*.jpg"
zip -r "%%~na.zip" "*.xml"
)
pause
```

I found some similar problems without solutions because publish my solution as "answer on my question".